# Difference between Events and Methods

Tags: c#, events, methods

I have some confusion regarding `Events`. What are the basic differences between C# Events and Methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# `Events` are a specific form of `delegates`. If you have programmed in other languages, like C++, you could compare a `delegate` to a function ("method") pointer - it points to some code in memory. When you call the pointer as a method, you actually call the method at the address the pointer points to.

This is necessary to provide decoupling between the caller and the callee - so you don't have to have all methods ready when you publish code that calls them (which, wouldn't be possible - the Forms controls developers can't possibly know the code that needs to be called when a `Button` is pressed). You call the pointer, and the other developer sets it to an appropriate memory address later.

P.S. `delegates` and `Events` however, have other advantages over plain function pointers - you can be sure that it will point to a good-looking method, taking the correct number and type of arguments and returning the correct type.

Answer (score 14):

A method is simply code contained within a class to implement a piece of functionality. All code in C# is contained within methods.

As for events, well, suppose you had a simple class which implemented a counter (lets call it the `Counter` object). Now suppose you wanted to let other objects unrelated to `Counter` know when the count reached 100. How would you do it?

A logical way would be to allow the other objects to specify one of their *own* methods they want to be called when the count reaches 100. Each object could then, individually, tell the `Counter` object which method they want to be called. The `Counter` object saves this list of methods and, when the count reaches 100, calls each of the saved methods in turn.

This is the how Events work - the `Counter` class contains an event member (called say, `CounterIs100`) which other object instances link one of their own methods to. When the `Counter` object detects that it has has reached 100, it *invokes* the `CounterIs100` member which, automatically, calls all the methods currently linked to it, thus notifying each object in turn that the count has indeed reached 100.
If no objects have linked a method to the CounterIs100 event member, it will be `null`, so there is no need for the `Counter` object to invoke the event member.

```
class Counter
{
   // this is the count field used to save the current count value
   private int count;

   // this is the event member which holds all the methods other objects have specified
   public event CounterIs100Delegate CounterIs100;

   // This is a method. It invokes the CounterIs100 event member if anyone has subscribed to it
   protected void OnCounterIs100()
   {
       // see if anyone has subscribed (linked) their method to this event
       if (CounterIs100 != null)
       {
          // invoke the event - this will call all subscribed methods
          CounterIs100();
       }
   }

   // This is a method. It increments the counter variable stored by this object
   public void Increment()
   {
      count++;
      // if the count is 100, invoke the event
      if (count == 100)
         OnCounterIs100();
   }

}

// This is a delegate. It is used to define a template for other objects wishing to
// subscribe to the CounterIs100 event. The methods other objects link to the
// CounterIs100 event must match this declaration (although the name can be changed)
public delegate void CounterIs100Delegate();

// This is a class, unrelated to Counter, but uses its events
class SiteHits
{
     Counter hitCounter = new Counter();

     public SiteHits()
     {
         // We want to know when the number of site hits reaches 100.
         // We could monitor this ourselves, but we know the Counter class already
         // does this, so we just link our method to its event
         hitCounter.CounterIs100 += this.WhenSiteHitsReaches100;
     }

     public void PageRequested()
     {
         // someone has requested a page - increment the hit counter
         Console.WriteLine("We've been hit!");
         hitCounter.Increment();            
     }

     // this is the method we want called when the CounterIs100 event occurs.
     // note that the return value and parameters match CounterIs100Delegate above.
     public void WhenSiteHitsReaches100()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Woohoo! We've reached 100 hits!");
     }
}
```

Comment: Another way for notifying would be using of Observer pattern. Then you can implement the same code without events. Why using events and not Observer pattern?

Comment: @CodePope because this answer was coded nearly 6 years ago. Coding paradigms change over time.

Comment: Observer pattern is much older than six years. It was existing at that time you wrote your answer

Answer (score 5):

***An event in C# is a way for a class to provide notifications to clients of that class when some interesting thing happens to an object.***

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

***A method is a code block containing a series of statements. In C#, every executed instruction is done so in the context of a method.***

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: A terrible answer to a bad question... Even I din't understand your explanation of events, and I have *years* of experience with C#!

Comment: @Vladislav Zorov Appreciate the feedback. Can you please let us all know a better way to answer such a basic question?

Comment: Wish I could downvote Validislav Zorov's answer. Maybe just english isn't your thing? It is such an easy explanation.Well done P.K.

Answer (score 0):

An event in .net is a pair of methods, one for "Add" and one for "Remove", each of which accepts a delegate.  Typically, the "Add" method will take the passed-in delegate and add it to either a list of delegates or a MulticastDelegate; passing a delegate to the "Remove" event which was previously passed to the "Add" method should remove that delegate from the list.  If one doesn't request otherwise, both C# and vb.net will by default automatically create "Add" and "Remove" events which will behave as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

This is from MSDN:

An event in C# is a way for a class to provide notifications to clients of that class when some interesting thing happens to an object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

A method is a code block containing a series of statements. In C#, every executed instruction is done so in the context of a method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, it is actually a duplicate of P.K's answer above :(